# How to change RDS timezone to Erope/London using db parameter groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, timezone, amazon-rds

I am trying to change the timezone of the AWS RDS instance which I've created in the Europe/London region. My Database is showing me UTC time when I fire `select now();` in the database. AWS says we can update our timezone for the database using group parameters, And I did, But I am just wondering there is a list of the timezone which are missing Europe/London. I just want to know that how can change my timezone of RDS sever from UTC to Europe/London or BST.
I've uploaded a screengrab of a list of timezone that I  am seeing in my RDS.

[image: AWS RDS missing Europe/London in timezone listing]